# Windows 10 iot speech synthesis language change

Tags: c#, windows-10-iot-core

I recently installed Windows 10 IoT on my Raspberry Pi 2 following this [tutorial](http://paulfasola.fr/en/add-voices-windows-10-iot-core-tts/), but it's not working.

```cs
foreach (var voice in SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices)
{ 
    Debug.WriteLine($"Name: {voice.DisplayName} Lang: {voice.Language} Type: {voice.Gender} Description : {voice.Description}");
}
```

On my first try, the above code showed "es-ES" language pack but, when trying to use the TTS it threw an exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
```

So, I did a fresh install again, copied again the files but, this time shows this:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Linq.dll.
```

Does somebody know how to properly install a new language pack on Windows 10 IoT core?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. How do you use the TTS? Can you show your code sample?

Comment: The code is the above foreach snippet, it should show the new "es-ES" language pack moved from my PC (Windows\SpeechOne_Core and System32\SpeechOne_core) on the debug monitor, but keeps showing only the english ones.

Comment: Can you show screenshots of the following two paths of Raspberry Pi: `\c$\Windows\Speech_OneCore\Engines\TTS\es-ES` and `\c$\Windows\System32\Speech_OneCore\Common\es-ES` ?

Comment: Found solution, read the answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks so much for your help, the solution was really easy, hope this helps somebody else. I did a fresh install again (using the flash image from Core Dashboard) and suddenly noticed that some old files were still there, even after the flash… So I did this:

1. I went to Partition Wizard and deleted the SD Card partition, then made a new Fat32 volume.
2. I reformatted the SD Card using Windows format storage tool and unticked the “Quick Format” option and selected default cluster. For a SD Card 8GB Class 10 took about 10 minutes.
3. Flashed again the W iot Core image.
4. Copied again Speech_OneCore\TTS\es-ES and System32\Speech_OneCore\Common\es-ES to my board and reboot.
5. Run again the code snippet to show available languages and it showed es-ES along en-US, I tested it with a TTS code and is talking in my mother tongue without problem.